# Dynamic_cast troubles over shared libraries

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm in trouble with some `dynamic_cast` on objects created by shared libraries:

The architecture is something like:

```
class A;
class B : virtual public A; // one of the several interfaces 
class C : public B; // defined only in the shared library
```

1. The main application load the shared library and requests a new
   object
2. The shared library creates a new `C` object but it returns a
   `dynamic_cast<A*>(pointerToCclass)` because the main application is
   unaware of `C`
3. When the main application tries to downcast to `B`
   from the returned `A` pointer it fails.

I suspect that some difference in the vtables created in the main and the shared code could be the reason. Anyway, initially I was unaware of this problem beacuse the main application
calls the method `void * A::getInterface( int ifEnum )`, so the downcast is performed successfully by the shared library code and returned as a void pointer. The main application then performs then a `reinterpret_cast` to bind the void pointer to the desired interface.

All worked till now, when a multi-inheritance schema (when `C` implements more than one interface) seems to be unstable and leads to Segmentation faults.

Are my suspects true?
There's a better way, or a well known method, to implement a similar architecture?

Thank you

---

I attach some semplified code of my real application with the essential actors.
First the common definitions:

```
class A
{
public:
  typedef A* (*getAobject_fn)(void);

  static A * Load( char * filename ) {
     void * objhlib = dlopen( filename, RTLD_NOW );
     getAobject_fn fp = (getAobject_fn) dlsym( objhlib, "getAobject" );     
     return fp();
  }

  virtual A * Create() = 0;

  virtual void * getInterface( int ifEnum ) = 0;
};

class B1 : virtual public A {
public:
  // some inline or pure virtual functions here
};

class B2 : virtual public A {
public:
  // some other inline or pure virtual functions here
};
```

The header of the shared library (actually the C class is not visible to the main application because the .so is loaded at runtime and .h not included in the main):

```
class C : public B1, public B2
{
public:
  A * Create() { return new C; }

  void * getInterface( int ifEnum ) {
     if( ifEnum==INTERFACE_ID_B1 )
        return dynamic_cast<B1*>(this);

     if( ifEnum==INTERFACE_ID_B2 )
        return dynamic_cast<B2*>(this);

    return 0;
  }
};

extern "C" { A * getAobject(); }  // probably useless
```

In the body of the shared library:

```
C obj;
A * getAobject() { return dynamic_cast<A*>(&obj); } // equivalent to return &obj;
```

And finally, in the main application:

```
// In the Init procedure
A * p = A::Load( "foo.so" );
A * pBobj = p->Create();   // pBobj is kept for the entire lifetime

B1 * b1 = reinterpret_cast<B1*>(pBobj->getInterface( INTERFACE_ID_B1 ));
B2 * b2 = reinterpret_cast<B2*>(pBobj->getInterface( INTERFACE_ID_B2 ));

// NOTE:
// b1 = dynamic_cast<B1*>(pBobj) and
// b2 = dynamic_cast<B2*>(pBobj)
// will fail
```

Comment: Why is there the needless dynamic cast from C to A?

Comment: @DieterLücking that dynamic cast is implicit but (I think) always a dynamic cast, so I preferred to not omit it.

Comment: Show the *exact* sequence of pointer conversions in play, both implicit and explicit, *as code* (not verbal descriptions scattered throughout the question).

Comment: @n.m. Yes.  There are at least two issues which may be involved here, one purely g++/gcc, the other C++.  Without exact knowledge of what he is doing, it's difficult to say which is at issue (but frankly, in his case, I'd resolve both).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How is the shared object loaded?  g++ uses the address of the
RTTI information to resolve `dynamic_cast`.  Traditionally, by
default in Unix, the first symbol to be loaded will be used by
all of the shared objects, so there will be no problem.  This
depends on the mode used in `dlopen`, however; if `RTLD_LOCAL`
is specified, the symbols in that shared object (and in shared
objects which are implicitly loaded as a result of loading that
shared object) won't be visible outside the shared object.
(I've had this problem with Java plug-ins.  Java loads the
shared object with `RTLD_LOCAL`, and `dynamic_cast` won't work
accross shared objects loaded implicitly by the shared object
Java loads.)

With regards to the main executable: most Unix linkers will make
the symbols available, as if the executable had been loaded
using `RTLD_GLOBAL`.  Most, but not all; the GNU linker, for
example, does *not* do this, and symbols in the main executable
are not available for shared objects.  If you need them to be
available, you must use the `-rdynamic` option when building the
executable (which translates to the `-export-dynamic` option to
the linker).  Alternatively, if you need to break your
application down into separate shared objects, you might
consider putting practically everything in shared objects, and
making the main executable nothing but a simple library loader,
calling `dlopen` on all of the shared objects, and then `dlsym`
to get the address of the actual function you want to execute,
and call it through the address.  (This is basically how we
solved the problem with the Java plug-ins.  All Java loaded was
our loader module, which then did the `dlopen`.  By doing them
explicitly, we could control the options to `dlopen`.)

EDIT:

On rereading your question, I'm not sure this is the right
answer.  You're passing through a `void*`, which means that you
have no access to the RTTI (or even to vtables).  The rules
concerning `void*` (C++ rules, this time, *not* g++) are clear:
the only thing you can do with a `void*` is convert it back to
the original pointer type.  In particular, the sequence
`Derived*` → `void*` → `Base*` is undefined behavior.
It will *typically* work if only single inheritance is involved
(but even then it is still undefined behavior), but not
otherwise.  So if the shared object converts an `A*` to
a `void*`, and the `void*` is later converted to a `B*`, you
have undefined behavior, and shouldn't expect it to work.
Converting the `void*` to an `A*` first, and then converting it
to a `B*`, should work.  Even better, however: declare the
function you're calling to return an `A*`, rather than
a `void*`.  In general, you should avoid `void*` as much as
possible, especially in C++.

Comment: I use hndl = dlopen( pathname, RTLD_NOW ), the shared lib has a static instance of C retrieved by the function A * getAobject() called after a dlsym( hnld, "getAobject" ). But I will use this A pointer just to call A->Create() that allocate a new C object, the one I will actually use in the main application.

Comment: I'm writing some additional code. In the meanwhile, the class C could implement several interfaces so I used the void pointers to avoid to define a function for each interface. I'll try the additional step to the ancestor class and let you know...

Comment: @Cappelli I'm not sure that I approve of the design, but if you really do only want one function, you might consider using a tagging interface: an abstract class with nothing in it except the virtual destructor: derive everything from it (virtually), and return a pointer to it.

Comment: @Cappelli Also: I would add the `-rdynamic` to your link of the main, and or in `RTLD_GLOBAL` in the `dlopen` anyway.  Even if they aren't causing problems at present, these steps may avoid problems in the future.

Comment: the function getInterface converts pointer to C to B1 or B2 then to a void. In the main the void pointer is converted back to a B1 or B2 depending on the request. So, can I still consider my code _technically correct_ ?

Comment: @Cappelli As long as the `void*` is reconverted back to the type which was used to create the `void*`, it's correct.  The sequence `B*` -> `void*` -> `B*` is legal.  The sequence `B*` -> `void*` -> _anything else_ isn't.  (Modulo a few exceptions like adding a `const`.)